# Regex: Remove the complete line when it contains a word

Tags: regex, grep, notepad++

I want to remove from my Database some Lines with Notepad++ or GrepWin. Any Line that contains MODsid must be deleted.

How could I do that?

The Lines

```
(10751, 1, '24555', '', 'product_info.php?products_id=206&MODsid=g8r9b625gev0eld02uaq5o2h74', '', '', '2013-07-05 10:31:28', 0),
(10752, 1, '69686', '', 'product_info.php?products_id=206&MODsid=geu3auqtc6gakfkh2lkkj18jn1', '', '', '2013-07-05 10:37:16', 0),
(10753, 1, '87957', '', 'product_info.php?products_id=206&MODsid=h3l5qr75ho7c8qn4uiqe3l5557', '', '', '2013-07-05 10:43:04', 0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the Notepad++ RegEx syntax, but in general:

Replace `\n.*MODsid.*\n` with `\n`

Comment: might want to include the leading `&` and trailing `=` to ensure this word isn't accidentally part of a larger word in some other field.